# How to send out email based on matching taxonomy terms in user profiles?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, webforms, emails

I'm using profiles 2 and have (one or many) taxonomy terms that can be selected by a specific profile type.  I have a webform that also has this taxonomy term in the select list.  When the webform is submitted, if it matches one of many taxonomy terms in any of these profiles I want an email sent to those profiles.  I can't figure out how to get [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to do this.  Any help is appreciated.

This is what I have so far.  I just have it posting a message right now to test, but I want it to email, but I can't find the data I need to compare in the Rules.

```
{ "rules_webform_email" : {
"LABEL" : "Webform Email",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "webform_rules", "rules" ],
"ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "webform_has_id" : {
      "form_id" : [ "form_id" ],
      "selected_webform" : { "value" : { "webform-client-form-3" : "webform-client-form-3" } }
    }
  },
  { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "webform" : "webform" } } } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Test submit webform\r\n[data:project_type-value]\r\n[data:project_description-value]" } }
]
}
}
```

The project_type is the taxonomy term in the webform.  I need to compare it with the field_service_provided (Term Reference field to the same taxonomy vocabulary) in the Profile.

Comment: please include an export of the rule you have so far, so that we just have to answer with how to correct or complete it ... FYI: should be easy ...

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please note you cannot change the meaning of a question after it got answers. This would invalidate the given answers, and it is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your question doesn't say so, from the format of your exported rule it's clear it is about D7. A possible answer to your question is by replacing the Rules Action in the rule you already have, and by also using the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module, as further detailed below.

#### 1. About the Views Rules module

The [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module makes [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) data available in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), enabling intuitive rule configuration for dynamic data. Some details from its project page:

> ... provides two types of elements in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), configured with a "Rules" view display:
>
> - **Views loop**: A views loop is similar to a regular Rules loop, but allows looping over rows of view results.
>
>   [image]
> - **Collect view result rows (action)**: This action collects each variable in all view result rows into list variables for use in Rules.
>
> ***Tip***: When selecting the data type for variables in the view, if the field is an entity identifier (e.g. Node ID), you can set the data type to the entity type (i.e. Node) to directly use the variable in Rules as an entity!

#### 2. Create a view of display type 'Rules'

After you enable the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module, you can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to create a view of those users that you want to send an eMail to. Add of view of display type ***`Rules`*** (important, that's the key to make it work!). Here is how you can add such display:

[image]

Next configure the row variables, by using the link that says "edit field info", as shown here:

[image]

You probably want to use one or more of the variables similar to those that are shown in this screenprint:

[image]

#### 3. Create a rule using the view of display type 'Rules'

Replace the Rules Action in your current rule, using these guidelines:

- Use the link that says `Add view loop` to add a Views loop, and select the "Rules" display created in the previous step.
- Configure the parameters and variable names.
- For each user contained in your Views loop, perform a Rules Action "Send an eMail", using the variables you configured at the end of the previous step (you may have to revisit the previous step to add more similar variables there if needed). If you created the *Rules row variables* as suggested in the previous step, your actual eMail can use tokens such as `[usermail:value]`, `[username:value]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Pierre - I had also considered doing it this way but couldn't get my view to work properly.  I can get the view to show all the information for all profiles but I need to just get the ones that have matching taxonomy terms, or can I set that part up in the rule?

Comment: @SharonDankwardt How many taxonomy terms do you have, just a few, or dozens of them? If you only have a few, you could possibly create a separate Views display for each of those values (which you hardcode as a filter in each Views dispay), and then combine that with the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module so that within your Rules Action you select the appropriate view based on the value of the taxonomy term. Could that be a aid solution? Btw, are you aware of [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I have 19 terms right now, but that could grow.  I was thinking I could use contextual filters on the view but couldn't figure out how to get that to work. i had also considered using a global text compare filter but couldn't figure out how to compare one of a list.

Comment: So.. I've got a view for one of the taxonomy terms that lists all matching profiles (I know I need to make the rest but I can't get one to work yet).  I've got conditional rules.  How do I get the taxonomy term on the webform to do the comparision?

Comment: I swtiched to an entity form as I thought it might be easier.  This is what I have so far but only saw the first message not the second one.

Comment: @SharonDankwardt please not the rollback of the latest edit you applied to your question (for reasons explained in the related comment below your question). I suggest you create a NEW question, in which you include the equivalent of that rolled back revision. If you want, with a link to your question here as a kind of "followup question".

Comment: Thanks Pierre - It would be great if I could solve this with the webform but don't know how to compare the a data field (Taxonomy term) on the webform to select the appropriate view as stated in your possible solution above. Any ideas?