# How to pass the Body field from a View to Rules?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, rules

**Context**: using the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module to pass a number of items to an action-loop in a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) component (Action Set).

In views (display: rules) I selected among others the Body-field to be used. This field appears to be an array of different things (value, summary, format), when I use the `[body-from-view:value]` in an action, it seems to be empty.

**Question**
I must have some settings wrong. What Data Type do I have to select in the Row Variables (Rules Settings) in the View for the Body-field? Or maybe I use a wrong Replacement Pattern in the Action?

**Note:** handling nid, email, title, date works very well, these have Data type like text, integer, date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you performed the steps similar to what is documented in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/236258/39516) to "[How to send out email based on matching taxonomy terms in user profiles?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236195/39516)". And while doing so, you probably used a field name like `body-from-view` in the "*Rules*" display of your view. I'm not sure if it is the only way to get it to work, but below is a possible solution to answer your question ...

## Part 1 - Getting it to work

#### Define the body field 3 times in your view

When adding the "body" as a field in your view, add that field 3 times. And when configuring these Views fields, make sure to use these ***field formatters***:

- Default (for the 1st "body" field).
- Trimmed (for the 2nd "body" field).
- Summary or trimmed (for the 3rd "body" field).

#### Select the 3 body fields 3 times in your view

When you edit the Rules settings of your view (by using the link that says "edit field info"), use 3 separate variables for each of the 3 body fields, e.g using machine names that look something like so:

- body-default
- body-trimmed
- body-summary-or-trimmed

I'm not sure (yet) about the most appropriate "data type" to use for these 3 variables, but in my case I just used "text".

#### Create your Rules Component using appropriate tokens

- Within the Rules Actions of your Rules Component, use the link that says `Add view loop` to add a Views loop, and select the "Rules" display created in the previous step.
- Within that Views loop add whatever Rules Action that fits your needs. E.g. to get started, just perform "Show a message on the site". At that point, you should have access to these token values that you're looking for (if you use the same machine names as suggested above):
- `[body-default:value]`
- `[body-trimmed:value]`
- `[body-summary-or-trimmed:value]`

## Part 2 - Showtime

Here is an example of the execution of a rules component, in which I implemented what's mentioned in "Part 1", using a Rules Action to show a message on the site, and which looks like so:

```
<hr />
Details about node with id = [node-nid:value] and title = [node-title:value]:<br /><br />
- <strong>body-summary-or-trimmed</strong> = [body-summary-or-trimmed:value]<br />
- <strong>body-trimmed</strong> = [body-trimmed:value]<br />
- <strong>body-default</strong> = [body-default:value]<br />
<br /><hr />
```

After executing it, and with 3 nodes that were included in my Views result, the result looks like so:

```
Details about node with id = 163 and title = Node with summary and separator line:

- body-summary-or-trimmed = <p>This is the summary of this node ... and there is really nothing else after this (in this summary) ...</p>
- body-trimmed = <p>This is the body of this node, which <strong>does have a summary also</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, and the separator line is inserted right here ...</p>
- body-default = <p>This is the body of this node, which <strong>does have a summary also</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, and the separator line is inserted right here ...</p> <p>And from here on there is even more content (after the separator line ...)</p> <p>Some more lines (1).</p> <p>Some more lines (2).</p> <p>Some more lines (3).</p> <p>Some more lines (4).</p>

Details about node with id = 162 and title = Node without a summary but with a separator line:

- body-summary-or-trimmed = <p>This is the body of a node which <strong>does not have a summary</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, and the separator line is inserted right here ...</p>
- body-trimmed = <p>This is the body of a node which <strong>does not have a summary</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, and the separator line is inserted right here ...</p>
- body-default = <p>This is the body of a node which <strong>does not have a summary</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, and the separator line is inserted right here ...</p> <p>And from here on there is even more content (after the separator line ...)</p> <p>Some more lines (1).</p> <p>Some more lines (2).</p> <p>Some more lines (3).</p> <p>Some more lines (4).</p>

Details about node with id = 161 and title = Node without a summary and without a separator line :

- body-summary-or-trimmed = <p>This is the body of this node, which <strong>does NOT have a summary</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, <strong>but no separator line</strong>  ...</p>
- body-trimmed = <p>This is the body of this node, which <strong>does NOT have a summary</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, <strong>but no separator line</strong>  ...</p>
- body-default = <p>This is the body of this node, which <strong>does NOT have a summary</strong> ...</p> <p>It has multiple lines, <strong>but no separator line</strong>  ...</p> <p>And there is even more content ...</p> <p>Some more lines (1).</p> <p>Some more lines (2).</p> <p>Some more lines (3).</p> <p>Some more lines (4).</p>

Component rule: Views Rules demonstration has been executed.
```

## Part 3 - Pieces of the puzzle

#### Exported View

Here is an export of the view I created (use the Views UI to import it in your own site, adapt the filter criteria to fit your needs):

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'details_about_nodes';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Details about nodes';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Details about nodes';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
/* Field: Content: Body */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_1']['id'] = 'body_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_1']['table'] = 'field_data_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_1']['field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_1']['label'] = 'Body - Summary or trimmed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_1']['type'] = 'text_summary_or_trimmed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_1']['settings'] = array(
  'trim_length' => '200',
);
/* Field: Content: Body */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_2']['id'] = 'body_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_2']['table'] = 'field_data_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_2']['field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_2']['label'] = 'Body - Trimmed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_2']['type'] = 'text_trimmed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_2']['settings'] = array(
  'trim_length' => '200',
);
/* Field: Content: Body */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['id'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['table'] = 'field_data_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['label'] = 'Body - Default';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'page' => 'page',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['operator'] = '>';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['value']['value'] = '10';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'details-about-nodes';

/* Display: ListToCreateRulesLoop */
$handler = $view->new_display('views_rules', 'ListToCreateRulesLoop', 'views_rules_1');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['rules_variables'] = array(
  'title' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'rendered' => 0,
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Content: Title',
    'name' => 'node_title',
  ),
  'nid' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'rendered' => 0,
    'type' => 'integer',
    'label' => 'Nid',
    'name' => 'node_nid',
  ),
  'body_1' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'rendered' => 1,
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Body - Summary or trimmed',
    'name' => 'body_summary_or_trimmed',
  ),
  'body_2' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'rendered' => 1,
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Body - Trimmed',
    'name' => 'body_trimmed',
  ),
  'body' => array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'rendered' => 1,
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Body - Default',
    'name' => 'body_default',
  ),
);
```

#### Exported Rules Component

Here is an export of the Rules Component I created (use the Rules UI to import it in your own site, adapt the Rules Conditions to fit your needs):

```
{ "rules_views_rules_demonstration" : {
    "LABEL" : "Views Rules demonstration",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "VIEW LOOP" : {
          "VIEW" : "details_about_nodes",
          "DISPLAY" : "views_rules_1",
          "ROW VARIABLES" : {
            "node_title" : { "node_title" : "Content: Title" },
            "node_nid" : { "node_nid" : "Nid" },
            "body_summary_or_trimmed" : { "body_summary_or_trimmed" : "Body - Summary or trimmed" },
            "body_trimmed" : { "body_trimmed" : "Body - Trimmed" },
            "body_default" : { "body_default" : "Body - Default" }
          },
          "DO" : [
            { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "\u003Chr \/\u003E\r\nDetails about node with id = [node-nid:value] and title = [node-title:value]:\u003Cbr \/\u003E\u003Cbr \/\u003E\r\n- \u003Cstrong\u003Ebody-summary-or-trimmed\u003C\/strong\u003E = [body-summary-or-trimmed:value]\u003Cbr \/\u003E\r\n- \u003Cstrong\u003Ebody-trimmed\u003C\/strong\u003E = [body-trimmed:value]\u003Cbr \/\u003E\r\n- \u003Cstrong\u003Ebody-default\u003C\/strong\u003E = [body-default:value]\u003Cbr \/\u003E\r\n\u003Cbr \/\u003E\u003Chr \/\u003E" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Great!It learns me even more than I asked for. Thank you very much.

Comment: You read my mind: I was searching how to this in the help pages. Up to the next step now (I want the result of the actions to be sent as html-mail thru mailjet-smtp)

Comment: @sigridt merci for the accept, and +1 ... If I may "suggest" a slightly different route for that next step: creating rules actions with some variation of sending eMail is ***old fashioned*** (they get lost, you get too much eMail etc). Instead you may want to consider using the "Message stack" (= a set of 3 modules), with great Rules integration. Have a look at [this](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/39516) for many, many links to great questions about the Message stack ...

Comment: looks interesting, I'll consider it.